# can't find referenced class issue?

Tags: android, facebook, picasso, shopify-app, okio

We are using shopify Android buy sdk to develop this app

```
  compile 'com.shopify.mobilebuysdk:buy3:3.1.1'
    compile 'com.shopify.mobilebuysdk:buy3-pay-support:1.0.2'
```

Error and Warning

```
warning: com.facebook.cache.common.cacheerrorlogger: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.cache.common.cacheevent: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.cache.common.debuggingcachekey: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.cache.common.noopcacheerrorlogger: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.cache.disk.defaultdiskstorage$fileinfo: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.cache.disk.diskcacheconfig: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.cache.disk.diskcacheconfig$builder: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.cache.disk.diskstoragecache: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.guardedby
warning: com.facebook.cache.disk.diskstoragecache: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.cache.disk.diskstoragecache: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.threadsafe
warning: com.facebook.cache.disk.dynamicdefaultdiskstorage$state: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.cache.disk.settablecacheevent: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.common.executors.handlerexecutorserviceimpl: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.common.executors.scheduledfutureimpl: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.common.internal.closeables: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.common.internal.objects: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.checkreturnvalue
warning: com.facebook.common.internal.objects: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.common.internal.objects$tostringhelper: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.common.internal.preconditions: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.common.internal.throwables: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.common.media.mediautils: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.common.references.closeablereference: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.guardedby
warning: com.facebook.common.references.closeablereference: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.common.references.oomsoftreference: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nonnull
warning: com.facebook.common.references.oomsoftreference: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.common.references.sharedreference: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.guardedby
warning: com.facebook.common.statfs.statfshelper: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.guardedby
warning: com.facebook.common.statfs.statfshelper: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.common.statfs.statfshelper: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.threadsafe
warning: com.facebook.common.util.hashcodeutil: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.common.util.uriutil: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.datasource.abstractdatasource: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.guardedby
warning: com.facebook.datasource.abstractdatasource: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.datasource.datasource: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.datasource.firstavailabledatasourcesupplier: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.threadsafe
warning: com.facebook.datasource.firstavailabledatasourcesupplier$firstavailabledatasource: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.datasource.firstavailabledatasourcesupplier$firstavailabledatasource: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.threadsafe
warning: com.facebook.datasource.increasingqualitydatasourcesupplier: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.threadsafe
warning: com.facebook.datasource.increasingqualitydatasourcesupplier$increasingqualitydatasource: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.datasource.increasingqualitydatasourcesupplier$increasingqualitydatasource: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.guardedby
warning: com.facebook.datasource.increasingqualitydatasourcesupplier$increasingqualitydatasource: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.threadsafe
warning: com.facebook.drawee.backends.pipeline.drawablefactory: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.drawee.backends.pipeline.draweeconfig: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.drawee.backends.pipeline.fresco: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.drawee.backends.pipeline.pipelinedraweecontroller: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.drawee.backends.pipeline.pipelinedraweecontrollerbuilder: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.drawee.backends.pipeline.pipelinedraweecontrollerbuildersupplier: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.drawee.backends.pipeline.pipelinedraweecontrollerfactory: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.drawee.controller.abstractdraweecontroller: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.drawee.controller.abstractdraweecontroller: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.notthreadsafe
warning: com.facebook.drawee.controller.abstractdraweecontrollerbuilder: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.drawee.controller.abstractdraweecontrollerbuilder$1: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.drawee.controller.basecontrollerlistener: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.drawee.controller.controllerlistener: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.drawee.controller.forwardingcontrollerlistener: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.drawee.controller.forwardingcontrollerlistener: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.threadsafe
warning: com.facebook.drawee.drawable.arraydrawable: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.drawee.drawable.drawableutils: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.drawee.drawable.roundedbitmapdrawable: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.drawee.drawable.scalingutils$interpolatingscaletype: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.drawee.generic.genericdraweehierarchy: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.drawee.generic.genericdraweehierarchybuilder: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.drawee.generic.genericdraweehierarchyinflater: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.drawee.generic.rootdrawable: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.drawee.generic.wrappingutils: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.drawee.interfaces.draweecontroller: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.drawee.interfaces.simpledraweecontrollerbuilder: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.drawee.view.aspectratiomeasure: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.drawee.view.draweeholder: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.drawee.view.draweeview: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.drawee.view.genericdraweeview: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.drawee.view.simpledraweeview: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.imageformat.imageformat: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.imageformat.imageformat$formatchecker: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.animated.factory.animatedfactory: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.notthreadsafe
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.bitmaps.artbitmapfactory: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.threadsafe
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.bitmaps.honeycombbitmapfactory: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.threadsafe
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.bitmaps.platformbitmapfactory: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.bitmaps.platformbitmapfactory$bitmapcreationobserver: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.cache.bitmapmemorycachekey: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.cache.bitmapmemorycachekey: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.immutable
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.cache.cachekeyfactory: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.cache.countinglrumap: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.guardedby
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.cache.countinglrumap: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.cache.countinglrumap: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.threadsafe
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.cache.countingmemorycache: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.guardedby
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.cache.countingmemorycache: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.cache.countingmemorycache: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.threadsafe
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.cache.countingmemorycache$entry: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.cache.defaultcachekeyfactory: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.cache.memorycache: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.cache.stagingarea: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.guardedby
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.common.imagedecodeoptions: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.immutable
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.common.priority: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.core.imagepipeline: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.threadsafe
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.core.imagepipelineconfig: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.core.imagepipelinefactory: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.notthreadsafe
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.datasource.abstractproducertodatasourceadapter: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.datasource.abstractproducertodatasourceadapter: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.threadsafe
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.datasource.abstractproducertodatasourceadapter$1: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.datasource.basebitmapdatasubscriber: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.datasource.closeableproducertodatasourceadapter: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.datasource.closeableproducertodatasourceadapter: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.threadsafe
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.datasource.listdatasource: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.guardedby
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.datasource.listdatasource: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.datasource.listdatasource$internaldatasubscriber: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.guardedby
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.datasource.producertodatasourceadapter: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.threadsafe
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.datasource.settabledatasource: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.datasource.settabledatasource: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.threadsafe
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.image.closeablestaticbitmap: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.guardedby
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.image.closeablestaticbitmap: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.threadsafe
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.image.encodedimage: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.image.encodedimage: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.immutable
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.listener.baserequestlistener: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.listener.forwardingrequestlistener: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.listener.requestlogginglistener: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.guardedby
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.listener.requestlogginglistener: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.memory.basepool: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.guardedby
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.memory.basepool$counter: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.notthreadsafe
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.memory.bitmapcounter: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.guardedby
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.memory.bitmappool: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.threadsafe
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.memory.bucket: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.memory.bucket: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.notthreadsafe
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.memory.flexbytearraypool: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.threadsafe
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.memory.genericbytearraypool: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.threadsafe
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.memory.nativememorychunkpool: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.threadsafe
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.memory.nativepooledbytebuffer: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.guardedby
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.memory.nativepooledbytebuffer: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.threadsafe
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.memory.nativepooledbytebufferfactory: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.threadsafe
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.memory.nativepooledbytebufferoutputstream: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.notthreadsafe
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.memory.oomsoftreferencebucket: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.notthreadsafe
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.memory.poolconfig: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.immutable
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.memory.poolfactory: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.notthreadsafe
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.memory.poolparams: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.memory.pooledbytearraybufferedinputstream: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.notthreadsafe
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.memory.pooledbytebufferinputstream: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.notthreadsafe
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.memory.sharedbytearray: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.threadsafe
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.platform.artdecoder: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.threadsafe
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.platform.gingerbreadpurgeabledecoder: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.platform.kitkatpurgeabledecoder: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.threadsafe
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.postprocessors.iterativeboxblurpostprocessor: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.baseconsumer: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.baseconsumer: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.threadsafe
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.basenetworkfetcher: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.baseproducercontext: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.guardedby
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.baseproducercontext: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.decodeproducer$progressivedecoder: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.guardedby
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.decodeproducer$progressivedecoder: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.jobscheduler: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.guardedby
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.localcontenturifetchproducer: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.localcontenturithumbnailfetchproducer: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.multiplexproducer: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.guardedby
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.multiplexproducer: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.threadsafe
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.multiplexproducer$multiplexer: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.multiplexproducer$multiplexer: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.guardedby
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.networkfetchproducer: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.networkfetcher: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.postprocessorproducer$postprocessorconsumer: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.guardedby
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.postprocessorproducer$postprocessorconsumer: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.postprocessorproducer$repeatedpostprocessorconsumer: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.guardedby
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.postprocessorproducer$repeatedpostprocessorconsumer: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.producerlistener: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.resizeandrotateproducer$transformingconsumer: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.settableproducercontext: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.threadsafe
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.throttlingproducer: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.guardedby
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.producers.webptranscodeproducer$webptranscodeconsumer: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.request.basepostprocessor: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.request.imagerequest: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.request.imagerequest: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.immutable
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.request.imagerequestbuilder: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.imagepipeline.request.postprocessor: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.facebook.imageutils.bitmaputil: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.nullable
warning: com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.path.parser.svgtopath: can't find referenced class org.kxml2.io.kxmlparser
warning: com.squareup.picasso.okhttpdownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.okhttpclient
warning: com.squareup.picasso.okhttpdownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.cache
warning: com.squareup.picasso.okhttpdownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.cachecontrol
warning: com.squareup.picasso.okhttpdownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.cachecontrol$builder
warning: com.squareup.picasso.okhttpdownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.request$builder
warning: com.squareup.picasso.okhttpdownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.call
warning: com.squareup.picasso.okhttpdownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.response
warning: com.squareup.picasso.okhttpdownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.responsebody
warning: com.squareup.picasso.okhttpdownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.request
warning: okio.deflatersink: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.ignorejrerequirement
warning: okio.okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.files
warning: okio.okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.path
warning: okio.okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.openoption
warning: okio.okio: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.ignorejrerequirement
```

When we are enabled  minifyEnabled true, it showing this errors and unable to developed release apk and there are more errors.

Comment: we added this and it is still showing this error messages
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
#### -- Picasso --
 -dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.**
-dontnote android.net.http.*
-dontnote org.apache.commons.codec.**
-dontnote org.apache.http.**
 #### -- OkHttp --

 -dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.internal.**
-dontnote android.net.http.*
-dontnote org.apache.commons.codec.**
-dontnote org.apache.http
 #### -- Apache Commons --

 -dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.**
-dontwarn okio.**